# Adding "--help" parameter to C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, console, environment

Almost all the .exe's I use via command line have a help function that gets called by the "--help" command.

How do I implement this in C#? Is it as simple as checking whether or not the parameter in args[] is the string "--help"??

Comment: Yes, it is as simple as that.

Comment: Why don't you use NDesk for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A C# snippet for processing the command line across multiple cultures is...

```
        string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            if (args[1].ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).IndexOf("help", System.StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0)
            {
                // give help
            }
        }
```

The detection logic can be combined with "?" or "/?" or any other combination that covers all expected cases.

NOTE: when you get the arguments from the Environment, arg[0] is populated by the loader.  The first 'user' argument is in arg[1].

Comment: Thanks for providing a cross culture approach. I haven't checked whether the code compiles or not, however, but it looks good.

Comment: I compiled it on both 4 and 4.5

Answer (score 22):

With *nix commands, it's common to obtain help either via `-h` or `--help`. Many windows commands will offer help with `/?`. So it's not bad practice to do something like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 1 && HelpRequired(args[0]))
    {
        DisplayHelp();
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}

private static bool HelpRequired(string param)
{
    return param == "-h" || param == "--help" || param == "/?";
}
```

Comment: @Christoph, nice edit there. Not sure how that `=` rather than `==` survived not being spotted for nearly two years! :)

Comment: No idea, probably because you have to edit at least 6 characters.
But I "hacked" it by adding static to the method too. ;)

Comment: @ChristophBrückmann, ah, that makes sense. I just assumed the `static` was a code improvement on your part, not a "hack" as I forgot about the 6 char limit. Thanks for both fixes anyway :)

Comment: @David Arno, I'd argue Christoph Bruckmann's edit is both code improvement and a trick to overcome the limit. The method doesn't require an instance. Making it static makes that clear. Although, this is a simplistic example and I wince just a bit at the method not being public - fine in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use an intersection over a small collection of help commands. If I constrain myself tightly to your question; it winds up looking like this:

```
static bool ShowHelpRequired(IEnumerable<string> args)
{
    return args.Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant())
        .Intersect(new[] { "help", "/?", "--help", "-help", "-h" }).Any();
}
```

Broadening the scope (just a little); I wind up with a method called `ParseArgs` that returns a `boolean` that is true if *either* **parsing failed** or **help is required**. This method also has an `out` parameter that stores parsed program parameters.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the arguments; sets the params struct.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="argv">The argv.</param>
    /// <param name="paramStruct">The parameter structure.</param>
    /// <returns>true if <see cref="ShowHelp"/> needed.</returns>
    static bool ParseArgs(IEnumerable<string> argv, out ParamStruct paramStruct)
    {
        paramStruct = new ParamStruct();

        try { /* TODO: parse the arguments and set struct fields */ }
        catch { return false; }

        return argv.Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant()).Intersect(new[] { "help", "/?", "--help", "-help", "-h" }).Any();
    }
```

This makes things very convenient in the main and allows for good separation between `ShowHelp` and `ParseArgs`.

```
    if (!ParseArgs(argv, out parameters))
    {
        ShowHelp();

        return;
    }
```

**Notes**

- Instead of having `ParseArgs` in `Main` one variation is to place the `ParseArgs` method into parameters struct as a static method.
- The `catch` should **only** catch parsing exceptions; code does not reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it as simple as checking whether or not the parameter in args[] is the string "--help"??

Yes.

This is why different console programs sometimes have a different convention for how to get at the help information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. AFAIK, same as compring the arguments and displaying some strings on the screen.

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    if(  args != null && args.Length == 1 )
    {
        if( args[0].ToLower() == "help" )
        {
             ShowHelpHere();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CommandLineParser nugget package. Then you can create an Options class, all metadata to provide help and validation. Pretty amazing and simple to implement.