# How to integrate c# help into console application

Tags: c#, cmd, integration, windows-console

Background Information (based on my first question):
i want to integrate in my "GUI.exe" (written in c#) a help function.
Then when i want to start in my cmd -> "GUI.exe --h" the help function.

Tried a stackoverflow- post:
I have try to use this solution: [Adding "--help" parameter to C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528669/adding-help-parameter-to-c-sharp-console-application).

```
static bool ShowHelpRequired(IEnumerable<string> args)
{
    return args.Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant())
        .Intersect(new[] { "help", "/?", "--help", "-help", "-h" }).Any();
}
```

Current problem:

I don't know where I can integrate the help function.
I don't know whether a particular setting in my Microsoft Visual Studio must configure.

In advance thank you for your Support.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Visual Studio. You have to include that code (probably) in your `main( args )` method.

Comment: thx for your answer. Now don´t Need to think about a config.

Comment: If GUI.exe isn't a console application, then first you'll have to call either WinAPI `AllocConsole()` or `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`. If you choose to attach to the parent console, note that CMD and PowerShell don't wait for a non-console child by default when interactive, so your output may get jumbled up with the shell's output.

Answer (score 5):

Call `ShowHelpRequired` in your main method :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        if(ShowHelpRequired(args))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Show help message here");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thx for your post. When i itry to call the ShowHelpRequired into my main method i get one failure (s. my next post)

Comment: static class Program
    {
             [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new GUI_Form());
        
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (ShowHelpRequired(args))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Show help message here");
            }
        }
    }

Comment: in your comment there are two main methods, please provide the failure message.

Comment: thx for your fast answer. Failure Message: "Compile wih /main to specify the type that contains the entry point"

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, my problem has unfortunately not been resolved

Comment: @Moha86B you need to have *only one* `Main` method, so remove the one with no parameter (eventually insert its content inside the one with args before removing it) and run.

Comment: @Rafalon thx for your comment. now i get this error => error CS0103: "The Name  'ShowHelpRequired' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Moha86B of course you need to add the `ShowHelpRequired` method you showed in your question, anywhere accessible from your `main` method

Comment: @Rafalon thx for the Information i already forgot to add the ShowHelpRequired. Now i have no failure. Now when i start the exe file via cmd = > "GUI.exe -h" then i will not get the help- Information (in cmd-Interface)

Comment: Here the code (from the main): static class Program
    {
        static bool ShowHelpRequired(IEnumerable<string> args)
        {
            return args.Select(s => s.ToLowerInvariant())
            .Intersect(new[] { "help", "/?", "--help", "-help", "-h" }).Any();
        }  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                if(ShowHelpRequired(args))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Show help message here");
                }

Comment: @Moha86B well, now **instead of** `Console.WriteLine("Show help message here");` you should write whatever you want the program to do specifically when you run it with "*GUI.exe -h*"

Comment: @Rafalon thx for your message It would be very helpful if you could give me a easy example to get a output in my cmd ("with GUI.exe -h").

Comment: @Moha86B I'm sorry for the late answer to your comment, but I thought my latest comment was already an easy example